# Why the observer can see values generated by the Observable before it was subscribed to it

Tags: rxjs5

I wonder why when subscribed to this Observable after a delay of 3200s, the observer will take the first values (from 0 to 2) which he normally would miss and just start from the value 3 :

```
const interval$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);


setTimeout(() => {
    interval$.subscribe({
        next : item => console.log("one.next : " + item),
        error : error => console.log("one.error : " + error),
        complete : () => console.log("one.complete")
    });
}, 3200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables are cold by default. This means that they are lazy and just become active when an Observer subscribes to them.

What you want is a hot observable. You can make a cold observable hot by calling `publish()` on it and call the `connect()` method on the hot observable. It then starts to emit values regardless of any observers. Also it shares the values between the observers as it can be seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khkhz6o3/).

See also [this medium post by Ben Lesh](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) that explains the differences between hot and cold observables.

Full code:

```js
const interval$ = Rx.Observable.interval(100);
const hotInterval$ = interval$.publish();
hotInterval$.connect();

setTimeout(() => {
    hotInterval$
    .take(5) // stop after five values for debugging purposes
    .subscribe({
        next : item => console.log("one.next : " + item),
        error : error => console.log("one.error : " + error),
        complete : () => console.log("one.complete")
    })
}, 320);

setTimeout(() => {
    hotInterval$
    .take(5) // stop after five values for debugging purposes
    .subscribe({
        next : item => console.log("two.next : " + item),
        error : error => console.log("two.error : " + error),
        complete : () => console.log("two.complete")
    })
}, 450);
```